# Trello C# api, .Boards.WithId() and .Members.Me() are always null

Tags: c#, trello, trello.net

I'm getting started with C# Trello API. I'we created simple console application, and ran it first to get access token:

```
static void GetToken()
{
     ITrello trello = new Trello("application key");
     var url = trello.GetAuthorizationUrl("Test api", Scope.ReadWrite, Expiration.Never);
     Process.Start(url.ToString());
}
```

`Process.Start` opened my default browser instance, I allowed access for the  application and on the next page got my token. Then I hardcoded the token and tried to implement [this example](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/wiki/Examples):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ITrello trello = new Trello("application key");
     trello.Authorize(token); // hardcoded token

     Member me = trello.Members.Me();
     Console.WriteLine(me.FullName);
}
```

But `me` is always null. What am I missing? Is authorization failed? If so, why don't I get `TrelloNet.TrelloUnauthorizedException`?

**EDITS:**
After a while I'we found some suggestion about `Json.NET` version included in the project in [this thread](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/issues/53) so I updated `Json.NET` and now I get `TrelloNet.TrelloException` with no message in line:

```
Member me = trello.Members.Me();
```

[image: TrelloNet.TrelloException without any message]

**StackTrace:**

```
at TrelloNet.Internal.TrelloRestClient.ThrowIfRequestWasUnsuccessful(IRestRequest request, IRestResponse response)
   at TrelloNet.Internal.TrelloRestClient.Request[T](IRestRequest request)
   at TrelloNet.Internal.Members.Me()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\Dropbox\Projects\TrelloManager\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 26
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```