# Got a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" exception while working with Trello

Tags: c#, trello.net

I am currently working with **TrelloNet** to develop my own Trello organizer application. Started with two piece of codes shown below ("**xxxx**" is my own authentication code and application key, masked for privacy purpose):

```
using System;
using TrelloNet;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITrello trello = new Trello("xxxx");
        trello.Authorize("xxxx");

        var myBoard = trello.Boards.Add("My Board");
    }
}
```

This code worked, a "My Board" board was successfully added.
But the second slightly modified code met an exception.

```
using System;
using TrelloNet;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITrello trello = new Trello("xxxx");
        trello.Authorize("xxxx");

        Member me = trello.Members.Me();
        Console.WriteLine(me.FullName);       //exception poped up here.
    }
}
```

After execution, there came an exception poped out at the line `Console.WriteLine(me.FullName);`, the exception is

- `NullReferenceException was unhandled`.
- `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TrelloOrganizer.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

object **trello** is indeed an instance of an object, why did I get this exception?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967865/trello-c-sharp-api-boards-withid-and-members-me-are-always-null.  Updating your references might fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much, will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the FullName property of the me object, which is null. Ensure that that object is set prior to using it. Or check for null after getting the reference to it. You may have to work back from here. I don't know what TrelloNet does when you try to Authorize and it fails. If it can return null from the Me() call, then you should check that it's not null first before using it. In any event, you should have some error handling in there too using a try-catch construct.

Comment: Thank you very much. @ManoDestra

Comment: Noticed that my answer was unaccepted. Is there a problem?

Comment: Trying to get my posting privilege back, unsuccessfully.